# getResource() to Path issue

Tags: java, path, nio, getresource

Within my program i have a line of code:

```
Path toRead = new File(getClass().getResource("/data.txt").toString()).toPath();
```

Whenever I try to run this I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4
```

As a normal File it seems to run fine but as a Path it messes up, is there a solution to this?

I need it as a Path in order to use `Files.copy()`.

The folder that data.txt is in is added as a source folder.

Comment: The call to `getResource` returns a URL path (`file:/a/b/c/data.txt`); it's not a `File` path.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Well I need that URL turned into a `java.nio.file.Path` in order to use `java.nio.file.Files.copy()`.

Comment: You shouldn't do that. If the file is packaged in a `.jar` file, the URL refers to a jar file entry, so it simply cannot be accessed like a `File`.

Comment: @CodedApple Use `Files.copy(InputStream, Path)`, using the result from `getResourceAsStream()`. Remember to close the stream when done, preferably by using try-with-resources.

Comment: @Andreas I only want to copy a file from within the jar to the directory that the jar is being run in, that's all.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, that worked...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707892/issues-using-getresource-with-txt-file-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *never* assume that a `URL` returned from `getResource()` is referring to a file. You should only ever use `URL.openStream()`. That is actually what `getResourceAsStream()` does.

```
try (InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data.txt")) {
    Files.copy(is, targetPath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
String pathToFile = getClass().getResource("/data.txt").toString()).toPath(); 
String  pathToFile = pathToFile.replace("/C:", "C:/");
Path toRead = Paths.get(pathToFile)
```

Comment: Why are you defining `pathToFile` twice?